# How to parse/identify double quoted string from the big expression using MARPA:R2 perl

Tags: regex, perl, marpa

Problem in parsing/identifying double quoted string from the big expression.

```
use strict;
use Marpa::R2;
use Data::Dumper;

my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new({
    default_action => '[values]',
    source => \(<<'END_OF_SOURCE'),

:start ::= expression

expression ::= expression OP expression
expression ::= expression COMMA expression
expression ::= func LPAREN PARAM RPAREN
expression ::= PARAM
PARAM ::= STRING | REGEX_STRING

:discard    ~ sp
sp          ~ [\s]+

COMMA                      ~ [,]
STRING                     ~ [^ \/\(\),&:\"~]+
REGEX_STRING               ~ yet to identify
OP                         ~ ' - ' | '&'
LPAREN                     ~ '('
RPAREN                     ~ ')'
func                       ~ 'func'

END_OF_SOURCE
});

my $recce = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new({grammar => $grammar});
```

`my $input1 = "func(foo)&func(bar)";` -> able to parse it properly by parsing foo and bar as STRING LEXEME.

`my $input2 = "\"foo\"";` -> Here, I want to parse foo as regex_string LEXEME. REGEX_STRING is something which is enclosed in double quotes.

`my $input3 = "func(\"foo\") - func(\"bar\")";` -> Here, func should be taken as func LEXEME, ( should be LPAREN, ) should be RPAREN, foo as REGEX_STRING, - as OP and same for func(\"bar\")

`my $input4 = "func(\"foo\")";` -> Here, func should be taken as func LEXEME, ( should be LPAREN, ) should be RPAREN, foo as REGEX_STRING

```
print "Trying to parse:\n$input\n\n";
$recce->read(\$input);
my $value_ref = ${$recce->value};
print "Output:\n".Dumper($value_ref);
```

What did i try :
 **1st method:**
My REGEX_STRING should be something : `REGEX_STRING  -> ~ '\"([^:]*?)\"'`

If i try putting above `REGEX_STRING` in the code with input expression as `my $input4 = "func(\"foo\")";` i get error like :

Error in SLIF parse: No lexeme found at line 1, column 5
* String before error: func(
* The error was at line 1, column 5, and at character 0x0022 '"', ...
* here: "foo")
Marpa::R2 exception

**2nd method:**

Tried including a rule like :

```
PARAM ::= STRING | REGEX_STRING
REGEX_STRING ::= '"' QUOTED_STRING '"'

STRING ~ [^ \/\(\),&:\"~]+
QUOTED_STRING ~ [^ ,&:\"~]+
```

The problem here is-> Input is given using:

`my $input4 = "func(\"foo\")";`

So, here it gives error because there are now two ways to parse this expression, either whole thing between double quotes which is func(\"foo\")
is taken as QUOTED_STRING or func should be taken as func LEXEME and so on.

Please help how do i fix this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use 5.026;
use strictures;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use Marpa::R2 qw();

my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new({
    bless_package => 'parsetree',
    source        => \<<'',
:default ::= action => [values] bless => ::lhs
lexeme default = bless => ::name latm => 1
:start ::= expression
expression ::= expression OP expression
expression ::= expression COMMA expression
expression ::= func LPAREN PARAM RPAREN
expression ::= PARAM
PARAM ::= STRING | REGEXSTRING
:discard    ~ sp
sp          ~ [\s]+
COMMA           ~ [,]
STRING          ~ [^ \/\(\),&:\"~]+
REGEXSTRING     ::= '"' QUOTEDSTRING '"'
QUOTEDSTRING    ~ [^ ,&:\"~]+
OP              ~ ' - ' | '&'
LPAREN          ~ '('
RPAREN          ~ ')'
func            ~ 'func'

});
# say $grammar->show_rules;

for my $input (
    'func(foo)&func(bar)', '"foo"', 'func("foo") - func("bar")', 'func("foo")'
) {
    my $r = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new({
        grammar => $grammar,
#         trace_terminals => 1
    });
    $r->read(\$input);
    say "# $input";
    say Dumper $r->value;
}
```

Comment: In my question I have mentioned that in the second method I tried PARAM ::= STRING | REGEX_STRING
REGEX_STRING ::= '"' QUOTED_STRING '"'

STRING ~ [^ \/\(\),&:\"~]+
QUOTED_STRING ~ [^ ,&:\"~]+ ; which is similar to what you are doing

Comment: i understood the problem; the problem is, I have included rules like : PARAM ::= STRING | REGEX_STRING
REGEX_STRING ::= '"' QUOTED_STRING '"'   STRING                     ~ [^ \/\(\),&:\"~]+
QUOTED_STRING              ~ [^ \/,&:\"~]+   ; here regex of STRING and QUOTED_STRING is different, then only it gives error

Comment: If i replace QUOTED_STRING with STRING; it will not give error

Comment: Can you suggest how do i resolve this? My regex of STRING and Quoted_STRING has to be different only

Comment: PLz help on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108574/parse-single-quoted-string-using-marpar2-perl

Answer (score 0):

2nd method posted in question worked for me. I just have to include :

```
lexeme default = latm => 1
```

in my code.