# Parse single quoted string using Marpa:r2 perl

Tags: perl, grammar, marpa, regexp-grammars

How to parse single quoted string using Marpa:r2?
In my below code, the single quoted strings appends '\' on parsing.

Code:

```
use strict;
use Marpa::R2;
use Data::Dumper;


my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new(
   {  default_action => '[values]',
      source         => \(<<'END_OF_SOURCE'),
  lexeme default = latm => 1

:start ::= Expression

# include begin

Expression ::= Param
Param ::= Unquoted                                         
        | ('"') Quoted ('"') 
        | (') Quoted (')

:discard      ~ whitespace 
whitespace    ~ [\s]+

Unquoted      ~ [^\s\/\(\),&:\"~]+
Quoted        ~ [^\s&:\"~]+

END_OF_SOURCE
   });

my $input1 = 'foo';
#my $input2 = '"foo"';
#my $input3 = '\'foo\'';

my $recce = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new({ grammar => $grammar });

print "Trying to parse:\n$input1\n\n";
$recce->read(\$input1);
my $value_ref = ${$recce->value};
print "Output:\n".Dumper($value_ref);
```

Output's:

```
Trying to parse:
foo

Output:
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'foo'
          ]
        ];

Trying to parse:
"foo"

Output:
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'foo'
          ]
        ];

Trying to parse:
'foo'

Output:
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '\'foo\''
          ]
        ]; (don't want it to be parsed like this)
```

Above are the outputs of all the inputs, i don't want 3rd one to get appended with the '\' and single quotes.. I want it to be parsed like OUTPUT2. Please advise.

Ideally, it should just pick the content between single quotes according to Param ::= (') Quoted (')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer regarding Data::Dumper output is correct. However, your grammar does not work the way you expect it to.

When you parse the input `'foo'`, Marpa will consider the three `Param` alternatives. The predicted lexemes at that position are:

- `Unquoted      ~ [^\s\/\(\),&:\"~]+`
- `'"'`
- `') Quoted ('`

Yes, the last is literally `) Quoted (`, not anything containing a single quote.

Even if it were `([']) Quoted (['])`: Due to longest token matching, the Unquoted lexeme will match the entire input, including the single quote.

What would happen for an input like `" foo "` (with double quotes)? Now, only the `'"'` lexeme would match, then any whitespace would be discarded, then the Quoted lexeme matches, then any whitespace is discarded, then closing `"` is matched.

To prevent this whitespace-skipping behaviour and to prevent the Unquoted rule from being preferred due to LATM, it makes sense to describe quoted strings as lexemes. For example:

```
Param ::= Unquoted | Quoted
Unquoted ~ [^'"]+
Quoted ~ DQ | SQ
DQ ~ '"' DQ_Body '"'  DQ_Body ~ [^"]*
SQ ~ ['] SQ_Body [']  SQ_Body ~ [^']*
```

These lexemes will then include any quotes and escapes, so you need to post-process the lexeme contents. You can either do this using the event system (which is conceptually clean, but a bit cumbersome to implement), or adding an action that performs this processing during parse evaluation.

Since lexemes cannot have actions, it is usually best to add a proxy production:

```
Param ::= Unquoted | Quoted
Unquoted ~ [^'"]+
Quoted ::= Quoted_Lexeme action => process_quoted
Quoted_Lexeme ~ DQ | SQ
DQ ~ '"' DQ_Body '"'  DQ_Body ~ [^"]*
SQ ~ ['] SQ_Body [']  SQ_Body ~ [^']*
```

The action could then do something like:

```
sub process_quoted {
  my (undef, $s) = @_;
  # remove delimiters from double-quoted string
  return $1 if $s =~ /^"(.*)"$/s;
  # remove delimiters from single-quoted string
  return $1 if $s =~ /^'(.*)'$/s;
  die "String was not delimited with single or double quotes";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result doesn't contain `\'`, it contains `'`.  `Dumper` merely formats the result like that so it's clear what's inside the string and what isn't.

You can test this behavior for yourself:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $tick = chr(39);
my $back = chr(92);

print "Tick Dumper: " . Dumper($tick);
print "Tick Print:  " . $tick . "\n";
print "Backslash Dumper: " . Dumper($back);
print "Backslash Print:  " . $back . "\n";
```

You can see a demo here: https://ideone.com/d1V8OE

If you don't want the output to contain single quotes, you'll probably need to remove them from the input yourself.

Comment: my $input3 = "'foo'''; If you give input like this, still slash come in the output .

Comment: also, if you give input as : my $input3 = "\"foo1\""; here also in output it doesnt show slash. So, why it shows in the third one?

Answer (score 0):

I am not so familar with `Marpa::R2`, but could you try to use an action on the `Expression` rule:

```
Expression ::= Param action => strip_quotes
```

Then, implement a simple quote stripper like:

```
sub MyActions::strip_quotes {
    @{$_[1]}[0] =~ s/^'|'$//gr;
}
```